# how to detect internet idle time?

Tags: delphi

how do i detect internet idle time(time since i used internet) using delphi 
something like:

```
begin
{ idle time detection code goes here}
showmessage('you have not browsed any websites or downloaded/uploaded 
for over xyz seconds');
end;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Internet idle time, or network idle time? For network you can periodically check outgoing packets and reset the idle time variable.

Comment: how do i do that, can you explain or point to a tutorial that teaches you how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Define `internet idle time`.
Then try [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation), for instance by [checking your NIC info using WMI](http://www.delphi-si.com/forum/prikazisporocila.php?tema=10015&mesto=def).

Comment: is there an alternative way of doing this?
kindly give an example

Comment: @Omair: first you need to define `internet idle time`, otherwise we cannot give you example code.

Comment: sorry i dont undurstand what you mean ,are you asking me to define internet idle time in my program or your asking me to tell you what i mean by internet idle time....sorry for my bad english

Comment: @Omair: don't worry about your 'bad' english: I'm not native either. Please define what you mean with 'internet idle time'. Depending on your definition, it becomes easier for the readers to answer your question.

Comment: by interney idle time i mean : time sice internet has not been working but i am still connected to internet eg i was downloading a file my download manager is no loger downloading file because internet is not working(although it is still connented) . i want to progamatically check when internet stops working and time since it has stopped working.thanks in advance